# How to add a list item to an existing unordered list

Tags: jquery, jquery-append

I have code that looks like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="/user/view"><span class="tab">Profile</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/user/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to add the following to the list:

```
<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>
```

I tried this:

```
$("#content ul li:last").append("<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>");
```

But that adds the new `li` *inside* the last `li` (just before the closing tag), not after it.  What's the best way to add this `li`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523100/7186739

Answer (score 853, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$("#header ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
```

Two things:

- You can just append the `<li>` to the `<ul>` itself.
- You need to use the opposite type of quotes than what you're using in your HTML. So since you're using double quotes in your attributes, surround the code with single quotes.

Comment: just as a side note, you can use prepend instead of append in case you want to add as the first element instead of the last

Answer (score 528):

You can also do it in a more 'object' and still easy-to-read way:

```
$('#content ul').append(
    $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href','/user/messages').append(
            $('<span>').attr('class', 'tab').append("Message center")
)));
```

You don't have to fight with quotes then, but you must keep trace of braces :)

Comment: Wouldn't your approach start new tags but not close them?

Comment: No, jquery creates tags using DOM manipulation, so it has only to know it's name

Comment: I love this. I hate messing with strings and quotes :) BTW: Other option would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/112000

Comment: This is by far the more preferable way, that is to use the more object-oriented manner.

Comment: You can escape any special HTML characters in user-input by using `$('<span>').text(unsafe_user_input)` instead of the direct `append("Message center")`.

Answer (score 57):

If you are simply adding text in that `li`, you can use:

```
 $("#ul").append($("<li>").text("Some Text."));
```

Comment: Works like a charm for me after trying all failed solution..

Answer (score 55):

How about using "after" instead of "append".

```
$("#content ul li:last").after('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
```

".after()" can insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. To insert into the middle of a list, you need to use `before` or `after`.

Comment: this combined with @Danubian_Sailor's answer hit the spot for me

Answer (score 30):

jQuery comes with the following options which could fulfil your need in this case:

`append` is used to add an element at the end of the parent `div` specified in the selector:

```
$('ul.tabs').append('<li>An element</li>');
```

`prepend` is used to add an element at the top/start of the parent `div` specified in the selector:

```
$('ul.tabs').prepend('<li>An element</li>');
```

`insertAfter` lets you insert an element of your selection next after an element you specify. Your created element will then be put in the DOM after the specified selector closing tag:

```
$('<li>An element</li>').insertAfter('ul.tabs>li:last');
will result in:
<li><a href="/user/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>
<li>An element</li>
```

`insertBefore` will do the opposite of the above:

```
$('<li>An element</li>').insertBefore('ul.tabs>li:last');
will result in:
<li>An element</li>
<li><a href="/user/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 18):

You should append to the container, not the last element:

```
$("#content ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
```

The **append()** function  should've probably been called **add()** in jQuery because it sometimes confuses people. You would think it appends something after the given element, while it actually **adds** it to the element.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#content ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For instance, [user *"Dipak"* wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/how-to-add-a-list-item-to-an-existing-unordered-list#comment14077672_1145215): *"Shouldn't it be '#header' instead of '#content'?"*

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
$("#header ul li:last")
```

try

```
$("#header ul")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
$("#content ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
```

Here is some feedback regarding *code readability* (shameless plug for a blog).
http://coderob.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/code-readability

Consider separating the declaration of your new elements from the action of adding them to your UL.. It would look something like this:

```
var tabSpan = $('<span/>', {
    html: 'Message Center'
});
var messageCenterAnchor = $('<a/>', {
    href='/user/messages',
    html: tabSpan
});
var newListItem = $('<li/>', {
    html: messageCenterAnchor,
    "id": "myIDGoesHere"
});    // NOTE: you have to put quotes around "id" for IE..

$("content ul").append(newListItem);
```

Comment: var newListItem = $('<li/>', {
    html: messageCenterAnchor
});

How do I get the li and id?

Comment: @jmogera, are you trying to set the id?  If so, you can just do that inside the { }'s. I updated the code above :)

Comment: The link is (effectively broken): *"Oops! That page can’t be found."*

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
// Creating and adding an element to the page at the same time.
$("ul").append("<li>list item</li>");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the shortest way you can do that:

```
list.push($('<li>', {text: blocks[i] }));
$('ul').append(list);
```

Where `blocks` is an array. And you need to loop through the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is another one

```
$("#header ul li").last().html('<li> Menu 5 </li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `li` in `ul` as first item using [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function of [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$("ul").prepend("<li>first item</li>");
```

Add `li` in `ul` as last item using [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) function of [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$("ul").append("<li>last item</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this thread - if you are *moving* an existing item you will need to use `clone` and then true/false on whether you clone/deep-clone the events as well (https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Example:
`$("#content ul").append($('.existing_li').clone(true));`