# How to add <li> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I want to add one more `li` at last but using JavaScript/jQuery

for example i want to add this `li` at last `<li><a href="#header" >Back to top</a></li>`

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Aliquam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Pellentesque</a></li>
        Here i want to add one more li using javascript
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('ul#nav').append('<li><a href="#header">Back to top</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have your HTML all set, including the jQuery library, you can test it interactively by typing just the actual append() line into the firebug command line. Once it works the way you want, paste the block as above into a <script> block in your <head> area.

Comment: but i'm getting this error in console  "ReferenceError: append is not defined { message="append is not defined",  more...}"

Comment: If you've got firebug, your HTML looks as it does in your question, and you are linking to a copy of jQuery, pasting this into the firebug command line: $("#nav").append('<li><a href="#header">Back to top</a></li>'); and hitting Return will work (just tried it).

Answer (score 4):

Use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) [function](http://jsfiddle.net/7n9Wj/).

```
$("#nav").append('<li><a href="#header">Back to top</a></li>');
```

Comment: Like in baseball, two outfielders yelling "I got it!" on an easy pop fly.

Comment: one more +1 for jsFiddle link.