# Adding a new element before the top element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul)

I have a `<UL>` which contains a list of `<LI>`. What I am looking at is on an event to add a new `<LI>` item as the first element on the `<UL>`. Can you please advice on how I can acheive this using jquery.

Example:

```
<UL>
   <LI>First Item</LI>
   <LI>Second Item</LI>
   <LI>Third Item</LI>
   <LI>Fourth Item</LI>
</UL>
```

on click of a button, i will need to add a new LI element as the first element in the UL,
which would look like the below

```
<UL>
   <LI>New Item is here</LI>
   <LI>First Item</LI>
   <LI>Second Item</LI>
   <LI>Third Item</LI>
   <LI>Fourth Item</LI>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("ul").prepend("<li>New Item is here</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function example_append() {
   $("ul").prepend("<li>New Item is here</li>");
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /><br/>
<ul>
   <LI>First Item</LI>
   <LI>Second Item</LI>
   <LI>Third Item</LI>
   <LI>Fourth Item</LI>
</ul>
```

Live Example @ http://jsfiddle.net/XNyJz/2/