# append li into an existing ul inside another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to append an li into an existing ul like here: [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul)

But in my code the li is an existing li from another html file.
So 'm having the products.html with an ul. In this html file I like to append the li

```
<li class="first-li" id="hotel_belle">
     <h2>Hotel Belle</h2>
     <div>
        <img class="sub-img" alt="picture from hotel" src="pic/products/HotelBelle.png" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <a href="#"><img class="btn-cart" alt="add this product to cart" src="pic/book/cart.png" /></a>
     </div>    
 </li>
```

into the cart.html:

```
 <div id="inner-cart-content">
        <ul id="content-cart">
            <li>
               //The new li element from products.html
```

in the JavaScript I wrote this:

```
$(".btn-cart").click(function(){  
var cart = $(this).parents("li").eq(0);

//$("#inner-cart-content ul").append('cart'); <--this is not working
});
```

So what do I have to do?

Comment: In your commented line, you do `$("#inner-merke-content ul")` but your UL id is "inner-**cart**-content". Besides, how is shown the page "products.html" ? In an iframe ? Loaded via ajax ?

Comment: oh sorry I edited this mistake :)
it's not an iframe - just a normal html file - for the first time I wanted to realize an prototype without content load by ajax - so the li elements are hard coded content

Comment: If the cart, where you want to put in the items, is not displayed on the same site as the products, then you will need an other solution.

Comment: Is is also a typo to do `.append('cart')` ? You should remove the the quotes, otherwise you are passing a string to the method and not the variable `cart`.

Comment: actually I'm not sure what to do know... to get the solution do I have to use data from ajax load?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn-cart").click(function(){
 var item = //grab what you want

 $("#content-cart ul").append(item);
 $("<div id="inner-cart-content">").show(); //After adding the item, show the cart
 $("div").delay(4000).hide(); And after 4 seconds hide it again!
});
```

Comment: with this I'm getting a blank page !?