# Load another page on an UIWebView when user swipes left

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, slider

I'm developing an iOS 4 application with iOS 5.0 SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have to make a slider showing web pages (5 or more). I've thought to add only one `UIWebView` and when user swipes left, I load another page. Maybe I can add a `PageControl` to show how many pages are.

My problem is how to handle swipe left event, and if there is a way to preload the next web page before it shows. In other words, if I have three pages and now I'm showing page one, I would like to preload page two. And, when user swipes left, and he see pages two I would like to preload page three.

Any clue?

Or

Do you know a better approach to make a web pages gallery?

I have tried to make a html slider, but it doesn't work because it gets a lot time to load html page. Here is a question related to it: [Unsorted list: load images or divs on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810515/unsorted-list-load-images-or-divs-on-demand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is to make a UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling, and paging enabled. Then you can put in every page of the scroll a webview, and using the delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You can start loading the webs when the user starts to scroll!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I'm doing it well. I have set delegate to UIWebView.scrollView, and it doesn't detect swipe left.

Comment: You have to create a scrollView, then put the webviews inside, and then do: scrollView.delegate = self;