# Replace multiline string with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, replace

probably a silly question. I'm trying to find and replace the following code in javascript. So that code is part of an ajax response with a lot of html code. 
So, I'm getting the ajax response, and I put it on a string variable, and using replace() I'm trying  to remove the following tags combination. Any idea will be appreciated?

```
    <ul> 


      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript replace uses `RegEx` (regular expressions)...

the pattern for your (invalid) tag-combination to remove will be:

```
result = subject.replace(/<ul>[\t\r\n ]*<\/li>[\t\r\n ]*<\/ul>/ig, "");
```

this replaces all `<ul>`'s, followed by an `</li>`, followed by an `</ul>` with only "newline, carriage-return, tabulator or space" between them.