# JQUERY: How to tag selected text using textbox as tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, textselection, jquery-tooltip

I'm building a website where i have pages with lot of text.
I need the ability to select text and than tag it with name and add it to list at the top of the page. the text can be very long so i'll have to use some tooltip for that.
i want something **like that picture i illustrated with photoshop**:

### [image]

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/279/) is the closest i could get to what i want but its **still not eneugh**.
**i saw some tooltips that may be helpful:**

Toltipster
Supernote

```
thanks
```

Comment: Which parts of what you're trying to do are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you were asking for but here is a solution for showing the tooltip next to the selected (or highlighted) text.

#### UPDATE 2017:

- using `window.getSelection()` to get the selected text
- `var x = e.pageX; var y = e.pageY;` to get coordinates at mouseup event (`pageX`, `pageY` take care of scrolling)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/f4qk677p/)

```js
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
  // add <li> to existing <ul>
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul
  $("#names")
    .append($('<li>').append(
      $('#selTxt').val()
    ));
  $("#tooltip").hide();
});

function placeTooltip(x_pos, y_pos) {
  $("#tooltip").css({
    top: y_pos + 'px',
    left: x_pos + 'px',
    position: 'absolute'
  });
}


$('#longtext').mouseup(function(e) {
  // get selected text
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text
  var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  $('#selTxt').val(selection.toString());
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
  placeTooltip(x, y);
  $("#tooltip").show();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #3333FF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>LIST</h3>

<ul id="names">

</ul>

<div id="tooltip">Selected text:
  <input id='selTxt' type="text"></input>
  <button type="button" id='addBtn'>Add</button>
</div>

<div id='longtext'>Oliver Twist, subtitled The Parish Boy's Progress, is the second novel by English author Charles Dickens, published by Richard Bentley in 1838. The story is about an orphan, Oliver Twist, who endures a miserable existence in a workhouse and then is placed
  with an undertaker. He escapes and travels to London where he meets the Artful Dodger, leader of a gang of juvenile pickpockets. Naïvely unaware of their unlawful activities, Oliver is led to the lair of their elderly criminal trainer Fagin.
  <hr>
  <br>Thomas "Tom" Sawyer is the title character of the Mark Twain novel Adventures of Tom Sawyer (1876). He appears in three other novels by Twain: Adventures of Huckleberry Finn (1884), Tom Sawyer Abroad (1894), and Tom Sawyer, Detective (1896). Sawyer
  also appears in at least three unfinished Twain works, Huck and Tom Among the Indians, Schoolhouse Hill, and Tom Sawyer's Conspiracy. While all three uncompleted works were posthumously published, only Tom Sawyer's Conspiracy has a complete plot, as
  Twain abandoned the other two works after finishing only a few chapters. The fictional character's name may have been derived from a jolly and flamboyant fireman named Tom Sawyer whom Twain was acquainted with in San Francisco, California, while Twain
  was employed as a reporter at the San Francisco Call.Twain used to listen to Sawyer tell stories of his youth, "Sam, he would listen to these pranks of mine with great interest and he'd occasionally take 'em down in his notebook. One day he says to
  me: ‘I am going to put you between the covers of a book some of these days, Tom.’ ‘Go ahead, Sam,’ I said, ‘but don’t disgrace my name.’" Twain himself said the character sprang from three people, later identified as: John B. Briggs (who died in 1907),
  William Bowen (who died in 1893) and Twain; however Twain later changed his story saying Sawyer was fully formed solely from his imagination, but as Robert Graysmith says, "The great appropriator liked to pretend his characters sprang fully grown from
  his fertile mind."</div>
```

---

I first get the coordinates at `mouseup`

```
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
```

and then use them to position the tooltip with a function `placeTooltip`

```
function placeTooltip(x_pos, y_pos) {
    var d = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    d.style.position = "absolute";
    d.style.left = x_pos + 'px';
    d.style.top = y_pos + 'px';
}
```

Here's the complete mouseup function

```
$('#longtext').mouseup(function (e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        placeTooltip(x, y);
        $("#tooltip").show();
        document.getElementById('tbNames').value = getSelectionText();
    })
```

Updated Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/BQSJ3/286/