# how to use html script template correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to generate some **li** element automatically and the way I was doing it it through a function that return text inside a loop, something like this:

```
function getLi(data) {
   return '<li>' + data + '</li>';
}
```

then I found a better way to do it by writing html inside a div:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="Template">
   <li id="value"></li>
</div>
```

and then I would change the id and value get the html and reset the element to original state:

```
var element = $("#value");
element.html(data);
element.attr('id', getNewId());
var htmlText = $("#Template").html();
element.html('');
element.attr('id', 'value');
return htmlText;
```

then I was reading on script template

and I figured this could be a better way of doing it,
However apply the previous code didn't work as the inner elements didn't exist according to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)

so how can I apply this?

**EDIT:**
I put inside a **ul** tag, I use this method to get the items dynamically

**EDIT2:**

```
<li>
   <a href="#" >
   <span>
   <span>
some text
   </span>
   </span>
</li>
```

this isn't necessarily what I have but something along the way

**Edit3:**
my ul does not exist orgialy it's generated dynamically 
I insist this is not a duplicate I want to know how to use a template with some dynamic variables

Comment: The 1st way is better, but it needs to be modified. By the way, what do you do with the generated LI? It'd be good get a bit more of context.

Comment: Right, I have posted my take. Take a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul)

Comment: @tawfekov Not a duplicate, the question is clear I want to use template

Comment: Why don't you use http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following way. It's clean, reusable and readable.

```
//A function that would return an item object
function buildItem(content, id) {

    return $("<li/>", {
        id: id,
        html: content
    });
}
```

In your loop, you could do the following. Do not append each LI inside the loop as DOM manipulation is costly. Hence, generate each item and stack up an object like below.

```
var $items = $();
// loop begin
var contents = ['<a href="#"><span><span>', data, '</span></span></a>'].join('');
var $item = buildItem(contents, getNewId());
$items.add($item);
// loop end
```

Just outside the loop. append those generated LIs to the desired UL, like below.

```
$("ul").append($items);
```

This is what I'd do and I am sure there are many better ways. Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't use this because my li actually have inner elements but didn't put them for simplicity

Comment: You can repurpose the function as you like to include children.

Comment: mmm would you please show me how? I'm new to jquery.

Comment: See my edits. You could nearly pass any content as children of the LI.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to upgrade to a modern JavaScript framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and then you could do it in one line using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

This would serve your purpose and make you more money as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to repeat this, use a templating system. Like [{{ mustache }}](https://mustache.github.io) or [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com).

If not, you can do this.

```
<ul>
  <li class="hidden"></li>
</ul>
```

And in Javascript

```
$('ul .hidden').clone().removeClass('hidden').appendTo('ul');
```

And CSS, of course

```
.hidden { display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function getLi(data,ID) {
   return $('<li id = "'+ ID + '">' + data + '</li>');
}
```

It returns javascript objest of Li..and you append it where ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `jQuery` templates, you can use [this link](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) which is a good one that I'm using.

You create your template and prepare your `JSON` object of data. After that things will be ready in one function call.